# Write a function to return a single corresponding value

Tags: r, function, return-value

This is a question of writing a function that return a single corresponding value of one column if I input the value of the another.
Here is my data:

```
MADRS   3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
HAM     3 3 6 8 6 3 3 9
```

for example, if I input MADRS=10, then my output should be 9. 
Here is my attempt,

```
madrs = as.integer (data [,1]) 
ham = data [, 2] 

conv <- function(madrs) { 
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
answer <-  ham[i]  
names(answer) <- "HAM"
return(answer)
   }
}

conv(10)

HAM  
  3
```

My output is always 3, instead of 9, no matter what madrs value I input. How do I fix my code? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Try `data$HAM[data$MADRS == 10]`

Comment: from your attempt it looks like `MADRS` and `HAM` are two columns of the dataframe. You need to subset them. Just keep `data$HAM[data$MADRS == madrs]` in your function.